# Write a PL/SQL block to insert numbers into the MESSAGES table. Insert the numbers 1 through 10, excluding 6 and 8

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude these numbers(6 and 8) when the loop happens.  Also, for this question, I CAN'T use FOR and WHILE loops. The question states to ONLY use a basic loop since the lessons after will teach me how to use it. Also, does anyone know if I'm allowed to insert multiple END LOOPs? It's also possible that this syntax may not be legal.
EDIT: I'm pretty sure I've tried doing IF v_results >10 THEN EXIT; but the same error message occurred.

```
DECLARE
v_results messages.results%TYPE := 0 ; --data type is NUMBER


BEGIN
LOOP
SELECT results INTO v_results
FROM messages;


v_results := v_results + 1;  --to increment
IF v_results = ANY(6,8)
   THEN 
    END LOOP; --i thought maybe if I added this, the loop can start over


ELSE
   INSERT INTO MESSAGES(results)  
   VALUES (v_results);

EXIT WHEN v_results >10;
END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

The error that I am getting.

ORA-06550: line 15, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with 
     <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Comment: Replace the intermediate END LOOP with a CONTINUE and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just avoid the 6 and 8 by adding 1 into it using the `IF` statement. There is no need for `ELSE` statement.

Also, you will need to use `MAX` function while fetching data from the `MESSAGE` table so that it can return the only max number. Without `MAX` function, you will get an error of -- multiple rows returned.

`END LOOP` must be associated with a single `LOOP` statement. so you can not write two `END LOOP` when there is a single `LOOP` statement.

```
DECLARE
    V_RESULTS        MESSAGES.RESULTS%TYPE := 0; --data type is NUMBER
BEGIN
    LOOP
        SELECT
            MAX(RESULTS) -- used max to find ONLY ONE MAX RECORD
        INTO V_RESULTS
        FROM
            MESSAGES;

        V_RESULTS := NVL(V_RESULTS, 0) + 1;  --to increment
        IF V_RESULTS IN ( -- used in here
            6,
            8
        ) THEN
            V_RESULTS := V_RESULTS + 1;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO MESSAGES ( RESULTS ) VALUES ( V_RESULTS );

        EXIT WHEN V_RESULTS >= 10;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=20da1794868527590b0f27643718671f)

Cheers!!

Comment: I tried running it, but the application that I'm using freezes. I'm using Oracle application express. I think something is off.

Comment: I TAKE THAT BACK. IT DOES WORK. THANKS.

Comment: I actually didn't know the MAX function would be important here. Since there is no data in the table, I thought it wouldn't make sense since I thought that if you loop in the beginning, v_results would be 1, and then it will be inserted, and then it will go back to the loop as 1 and then be incremented again.

Comment: Yes, and you will learn more about LOOPs in your next sessions. COOL. Keep coding!!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
i number:=1;
begin
    loop
         if i not in(6,8) then
            insert into msg values(i); 
        end if;
        i :=i+1;
    exit when i>10;    
    end loop;
end;
```